# Maven over Ant for an Non Java CI/CD

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant

Is there any advantage of using Maven over Ant for a (Non JAVA) CI/CD implementation where most of the tasks are executed by an .exe with some parameters and the same task would be invoked from Jenkins. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Depends.  What do you need to do?

Comment: All that I would be doing is invoking an .executable with different set of parameters

Comment: Then why use jenkins for it?  What is it you want from the CI/CD engine that a simple script cannot do?

Comment: It also involves checking-out the code from source control and passing of parameters to consequent jobs

Comment: In that case, why even use ant or maven? Jenkins allow for free-form jobs where you can do anything you want.

Comment: I have hundreds of parameters to be hanlded and passed to script, free-form jobs won't be an option. Just watned to know if there is any specific advantage to using maven over Ant for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that Ant and Maven are quite different in their approach to what they do.

- Ant is essentially a scripting language disguised as XML
- Maven prefers static configuration of plugins each of which does a rather well-defined job.

In my experience this mean that Maven is typically much, much better supported in Java IDE's making it easier to develop the functionality you need locally, and choose the most suitable IDE at any given moment in time.  I have successfully used the same, unchanged Maven project in Netbeans, IntelliJ and Eclipse.

If I understand your very vague description correctly, I would write a small jUnit test for each invocation of your EXE providing the parameters (or a parameterized test suite depending on how your parameters are stored). This allows you to rerun just one test or those who failed easily.  Make the tests independent so they can execute in any order.  A bit of elbow grease here, goes a very long way.

This approach allows for Jenkins to understand much more about your tests.  Run them in parallel if needed.  Generate a report at the end if needed.  Only continue to deployments if test succeed.  In ant, you need to hand-code most of this yourself.

Note:  Maven is rather picky and has a steep learning curve.  Follow conventions as much as you possibly can.

Comment: Currently I have written the same as an Ant Script with multiple tasks like code validate( invoke executable with file parameters) , build ear ( invoke .exe with parameters) , deploy ear ( invoke differnet .exe with parameters) and start application ( again invoke execuble with different parameters). I am invoking these Ant tasks as part of different jenkins pipeline projects. Just wondering if there is any added added advantage of doing the same in Maven.

Comment: Also some file processing like replacing texts and deleting directories.. Nothing much apart from that

Comment: With ant you have to do _everything_ yourself.  If that is fine, there is no advantage.

Comment: those api are self sufficient and handle most of my stuffs like packaging and buidling ears..so I belive I would go ahead with Ant

Comment: Great - glad to have helped you reach a decision.  However, when you grow tired of reinventing the wheel in every new project you have to do (and backporting new ant-scripts changes to your old projects) consider revisiting this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You are building non-Java.  I'd go with Maven.  That said, there's a lot of pain in both approaches.

Maven declares a single output artifact.  That's a blessing and a curse.  If you want a custom build cycle, which is a set of steps to build a particular item, you can easily add it in with Maven.  There have been plenty of examples of Maven building shared object libraries from C/C++ sources (typically for inclusion into Java via JNI).  As long as you define your artifact, and define a custom lifecycle to build it, you can get along with Maven just fine.  The main problems come in when you have few existing Maven targets to include in your lifecycle, and you need to write nearly all of them.

If you have a lot of stuff to "code" into your build system, then Ant is the better choice for minimizing the coding effort.  That said, it is firmly a Make-like tool configured in XML, with a few very nice features that can hide some of its Make heritage.  It is not too hard to code up a few extra Ant Tasks, and sourcing them into an Ant build is not difficult either.  That said, there is no "common" build project structure, and your maintenance of the ant build.xml file will tend to suffer over time because of that lack.  Also, the information common to a project has no predeclared structure, and you will find it tends to become poorly managed over time due to this fact.

So, Maven is likely a better long-term solution; but, it also has a deeper learning curve and a bit more upfront effort in setting up your builds.  Ant will get you out the door faster, but will likely leave you with a project that (from a build perspective) has less structure, no per-build reporting, and may (as a result) cost more time and effort to update over time.

Comment: If all that is requested is the invocation of X jobs and there is no interest in an output artifact,  that is not a big limitation.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Then it seems you've found your answer!  Congratulations.  That said, there have been many Ant projects that grew to need "just a little more" than what they started with, over time.  Perhaps yours won't, perhaps it will.  Maven forces a structure, and that's both a blessing and a curse, depending on how well you can live with that kind of rigor.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If you're using ecplise, then you should know that eclipse really doesn't build a Maven project by leveraging Maven.  Rather it attempts to digest the Maven project into an equivalent Eclipse configuration.  For very simple projects, it works.  I wouldn't extrapolate my Eclipse Maven experiences to other environments.  Netbeans properly delegates builds to Maven, and it's 100x better than Eclipse (in this one aspect).  Even command line Maven is better (in my opinion) than Eclipse Maven.

Comment: I'm not the OP.  I just reflected on what has been said about what this is needed for.  I have walked down the ant path using ant4eclipse all the way to where it simply became too brittle - Maven, even though I strongly disagree with some parts of its design, got the "static configuration ONLY" part right.

Comment: Not as I remember it - ant4eclipse read eclipse configuration files and made their contents available to the ant scripts.  You still had to redo functionality in ant too.  These days I primarily use IntelliJ as that is what is provided for those who wants it at my current job.  Its Maven integration is quite good.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sorry, I  did Maven work in an Eclipse environment for about three years.  That's why there is a "maven ecplise plug-in" for Maven.  It basically reports back to Eclipse what directories Eclipse has to re-scan to discover the Maven output.  And that's if you configure Eclipse to really launch Maven (which is not the default).  I assure you, if you look into it, you'll find what I say is true. http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ This is why people recommend using the eclipse command line tools to build maven projects managed by eclipse.

Comment: I know.  m2e is a quite different beast than ant4eclipse, and I am quite familiar with it.